# How can you use Controller A to access table B (in the same database)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have a "jobs" model in my RoR project and i need the controller to access a table other than "jobs" in the database.

Calling:
@var = Job.find(:all)
is not problem, but calling

@var = TableB.find(:all)

gets "undefined local variable or method `tableB'" for JobsController:Class

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What is TableB? Table name? Model name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All models are available in all controllers.

So from your exact input I would say `tableB != TableB` could be the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it's something along these lines.  You shouldn't have any trouble getting the model from any controller, as long as you're following ActiveRecord naming conventions, i.e. singular camelcase starting with a capital letter.

Comment: thanks! i was using the filename - table_b.rb - instead of the actual class name - tableB.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a TableB model?

```
script/generate model TableB
```

You might also be trying to have a model that corresponds to a different table name (not sure exactly what you're asking):

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base 
    set_table_name 'TableB' 
end
```

Comment: yes, I have a model TableB. 

both "Job" and "TableB" are tables and models in my Rails project. to rephrase my question, how do you get a controller to manipulate objects that are not in the controller's class? in this case, the controller is named "Jobs" and the class/model I need to manipulate is "tableB."